fast CRC computation
I have two implementations of the crc calculation.
The crc_classic is based on the typical implementation you can find for example on Wikipedia
The second one might be found in D.3.2 here IO-Link
I'm looking for an explanation why the second one does the same as the first one.
The second one is typically considered faster. It uses a running calculation, while the first one uses an in-place calculation on the input data. So far so good.
But I find it hard to see why this is the same.
I would never have found the second implementation myself.
Is there maybe a transformation from one into the other?
Or another good explanation or proof why they give the same output?
def crc_classic(input_bitstring, polynomial_bitstring):
    len_input = len(input_bitstring)

    initial_padding = (len(polynomial_bitstring) - 1) * '0'
    input_padded_array = list(input_bitstring + initial_padding)

    while '1' in input_padded_array[:len_input]:
        cur_shift = input_padded_array.index('1')

        for i in range(len(polynomial_bitstring)):
            input_padded_array[cur_shift + i] = str(int(polynomial_bitstring[i] != input_padded_array[cur_shift + i]))
    return ''.join(input_padded_array)[len_input:]


def crc_running(input_bitstring, polynomial_bitstring):
    len_input = len(input_bitstring)

    result = '000'

    for n in range(len_input):
        if result[0] != input_bitstring[n]:
            result = result[1:] + '0'
            result = ''.join(str(int(polynomial_bitstring[i+1] != result[i])) for i in range(len(result)))
        else:
            result = result[1:] + '0'
    return result


def main():
    input_bitstring = '11010011101100'
    polynomial_bitstring = '1011' #must have a leading 1
    print(crc_classic(input_bitstring, polynomial_bitstring))
    print(crc_running(input_bitstring, polynomial_bitstring))

main()


Do you understand what CRC actually means, as a polynomial division in $GF(2)$?

Could you please provide more details on the second implementation? Providing a link to a 178 page PDF is a serious impediment to reviewing the second implementation (I'm assuming the implementation doesn't requires 100+ pages of reading).

@MotiNK
It is in chapter D.3.2. That is all the information I got so far. I have seen implementations of this algorithm and I know it is correctly working.

@Pseudonym
I think I don't fully understand what GF(2) means, but I understand the Computation as described by Wikipedia.

If I remember right, CRC is defined for sequences of bits, but you can take an input byte and pre-calculate what the next 8 operations would be, and what their effect would be. So with a table of 256 .= 2^8 values you can process eight bits at a time. Or with a table wit 65,536 entries, it’s 16 bits at a time.
And with Python it depends on the actual implementation of your code, so you need to measure the speed. And to be honest, you are better off with a library written in C. And using character arrays representing bits with ‘0’ and ‘1’ makes me cringe.

The implementation in Python is only for illustration. I might use C or C++.
I may have been unclear, but the question which one is faster or using a table, isn't of particular interest at the moment.
The question really boils down to why both implementations do the same.
